# using name in angular 2 when setting up routes

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2 app which was written in angular 2 beta 14. I am upgrading it to rc5. I am using the latest router , my package json contains `"@angular/router": "3.0.0-rc.1"`

Previously routes were configured like :

```
{path:'/...',name:'LoggedIn',component:LoggedInComponent},
{path:'/auth', name:'Auth', component:AuthComponent}
```

Now I am doing like this

```
import { RouterModule , Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthComponent} from "./auth/auth.component";
import {LoggedInComponent} from "./auth/logged-in.component";
import {LOGGED_IN_ROUTES} from "./auth/logged-in.routes";
const APP_ROUTES : Routes = [
    { path : '/...' , name :'LoggedIn' , component : LoggedInComponent , children : LOGGED_IN_ROUTES},
    { path : '' , component : AuthComponent},
    { path : 'auth' , component : AuthComponent},

];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

I am getting error like

```
Type '({ path: string; name: string; component: typeof LoggedInComponent; children: Route[]; } | { path...' is not assignable to type 'Route[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; name: string; component: typeof LoggedInComponent; children: Route[]; } | { path:...' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
    Type '{ path: string; name: string; component: typeof LoggedInComponent; children: Route[]; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'name' does not exist in type 'Route'.
```

Comment: Remove `name` from your Route config...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is deprecated now, API has been upgraded since beta, you may read more about it [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html).

To check how to configure route and the schema of Routes array see [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/Routes-type-alias.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I see there is still a 'name' property on `route.component`. I can even use and log it - but it still throws me this error when I try to serve the project, and the serve fails. If I remove `this.route.component.name` from my code, the app serves properly - then I'm free to re-insert this.route.component.name and it works - the correct data is displayed.

What's an alternative to route.component.name if I want to find out the current component?

Answer (score 0):

Pass it as data via the data key, like so:

```
{ path: 'your_path', component: yourComponent, data: { name: 'your_path_name' }}
```

Read more: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration